# mypy: incompatible type[class], expected class

Tags: python, mypy

I've got a problem with mypy when handing a class-object as variable to a function:

```
from PIL import Image
def save_img(img: Image.Image) -> None:
    img.save("file.png")
img = Image.open("any_image.png")
save_img(img)   # mypy-error save_img has incompatible type "Type[Image]"; expected "Image"
```

If I change `save_img` like the follwoing, I create a different mypy error:

```
def save_img(img: Type[Image.Image]) -> None:
    img.save("file.png")   # mypy-error: missing positional argument 'self'
```

How do I correctly annotate the type in the function definition?

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example. Your first code sample passes type checking with `mypy==0.950, Pillow==9.1.0, types-Pillow==9.0.14` without any modifications. It is also perfectly semantically valid. Your second example shouldn't work, because `save_img` expects `Image` instance, not class.

Comment: Thanks for the hint that it works. In the example I tried to replicate what's happening in the project, so my actual code is a bit different. But I think I've found the issue, after your comment. It is in the variable that I hand over to the function `save_img`. This variable had the wrong type annotation. That's why mypy was complaining. So you actually helped.